# How to execute main method of a Runnable JAR from a different Java code?

Tags: java

I have a `test.jar`. This `jar` has only one class. All it does is delete a folder

```
import java.io.File;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File fileTest = new File("C:\\Users\\...\\test"); 
        fileTest.delete();          
    }
}
```

---

I need to execute this external `test.jar` from other java application

This is what I tried

```
  ClassLoader pluginLoader = new PluginClassLoader(new URL("file:\\\\C:\\Users\\ . . .\\test.jar"));
  Class<?> pluginClass = pluginLoader.loadClass("Test");        
  Plugin plugin = (Plugin) pluginClass.newInstance();  
  pluginClass.getMethod("main"); // trying to get main method but it throw no such method exception
```

Comment: First, you have to get class with the main method (currently hardcoded as `"Test"` in your example) and then get a static method name `main` with takes a String array as sole parameter. You are looking for a method named `main` which takes no arguments.

Comment: There may be other problems, but `getMethod("main")` is looking for a method named "main" that has _zero parameters_; you should be using `getMethod("main", String[].class)`. See the documentation of [`Class#getMethod(String,Class...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...)) for more information.

Comment: THank you  . Is there any shortcut method? `java.utils.runJAR(String jarLocation)`

Comment: Do you need to run this code in the same JVM or can you launch a separate process?

Comment: Yes I need it to be run within the same JVM like a plugin. But definitely not like `Runtime`. The jar needs to be loaded like a plugin

Comment: The correct way to implement a plugin architecture is with the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class.  Also, URLs *always* use forward slashes (`/`), never backslashes, regardless of the underlying platform.

Comment: Thank you. i was using example code from here https://blog.jayway.com/2014/06/13/sandboxing-plugins-in-java/ They dont use ServiceLoader

Comment: That blog is wrong.  Reflection is probably the worst way to load plugins (or do anything), because it’s error-prone and slow.  ServiceLoader is designed to handle this case, cleanly and safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to implement a plugin architecture is with the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class.  But your case seems to be a much simpler one, since your `Test` class only has one static method.

First, the `main` method of class `Test` is `static`.  This means no instance needs to be created in order to call it, so you should remove the call to `pluginClass.newInstance()`.

Second, a method in Java is defined by its *signature.*  The signature is identified by both the method name and the types of the method arguments.  There is no method with the signature `main()`, but there is a method with the signature `main(String[])`.

You need to specify the full signature of the method you’re requesting:

```
pluginClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
```

Finally, you can invoke it:

```
Method main = pluginClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
main.invoke(null, new Object[] { new String[0] });
```

The first argument to `main.invoke` is null, because it’s a `static` method and there is no specific instance required.

Comment: Thank you . I'm gettin `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments` when `invoke()`

Comment: @john Updated code.  I forgot `new String[0]` by itself was interpreted as a varargs list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("java -jar test.jar");
```

Comment: THank you Oleg. I was looking for a `plugin` solution. It needs to run within the same JVM not like separate process.